# localhost not working but 127.0.0.1 does, DYMO label software issue

Tags: localhost, hosts, dymo

Not specifically code related but it is something networking and I think my hosts file might be the culprit.

I am using the DYMO software to print from a webpage and this requires that a url:

```
https://localhost:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/Check
```

Works, now this does work when their service is turned on:

```
https://127.0.0.1:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/Check
```

My hosts file looks like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I have turned off `tls 1.3` which was the recommended fix from the dymo guys.

any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

this is because some web server have problem with https protocol with localhost.
There are different ways to make it work.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec

But if it is not a problem you can just continue with the IP address.

If you have a webserver local with http only in that case both work the same.